# 2006 Pontiac G6 - brake lights turn on when brakes aren't pressed

Tags: brakes, lights

The brake lights will turn on when the brakes aren't pressed, but once I press them in far enough (not very far) they turn off, then once I press the brakes hard enough to the point where I'm actually slowing down, they turn back on.

Cruise control doesn't work while the lights are on and the brakes aren't pressed. If I have the brake pedal in the "dead zone" where the lights are off, then turn on cruise control, then let go of the brakes, a few seconds later, the brake lights will turn back on and cruise control will turn back off.

This problem will sometimes fix itself for days at a time, or maybe for just one drive, but then comes back.

I haven't been able to find anything about this particular problem, but I've seen that when brake lights stay on, it's probably the brake light switch, or the wiring connected to it, or maybe even a fuse. I'm thinking it's the switch though, given that the lights turn on and off depending on the position of the pedal.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: I agree it's switch related. I would check for an adjustment before replacing the switch. Sometimes the pedal stop may become unadjusted.

Comment: @vini_i what do you mean unadjusted? Also, what is a pedal stop?

Comment: When the pedal comes all the way up there is a stop that it rests against. Sometimes that stop is adjustable. This could allow you to bring the pedal back into the lights off territory. The switch may be adjustable (sort of). I've seen two switch adjustment schemes and both were one time. One had you install the switch while holding the pedal down. Then releasing the pedal made a crunch adjusting the switch. The second had you install the switch and only then plug it in. Inside the plug was a button that when pushed in set the switch height.

Comment: I found this video, which shows a fix that involves applying dielectric grease to the body computer https://youtu.be/N7RA7Mc_tLo I may try that if the brake switch or pedal stop doesn't need adjusting. Apparently this is a common problem with GPS, so much so that GM issued a recall for it

Comment: Same issue. Did any of this fix the problem???